# "For" means in —"Gift for languages"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

She has a gift **for** languages.

I know gift means in the context— talent to do something, but i am having doubt regarding the meaning of "for" in the sentence??

Comment: "For" doesn't really have a special meaning here. "To have a gift for [something]" is a common expression, an idiom. You need to use "for" here, because it's a fixed expression - you can't change it.  It means "to be talented or skilled at [doing something]". See [this defintion](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+gift+for+something). For idioms or expressions, you shouldn't really try to pick apart the meanings of the words literally. They rarely have a literal meaning.

Comment: @BillyKerr  I can say she is very good at (teaching languages) instead of (learning languages).

Comment: I think it's the full OED section **IX** -***Expressing reference.*** Specifically, subdefinition 25.a - ***With regard or respect to, as regards, concerning.*** For[!] which their examples include *How are we doing for time? Are we late?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then, She is good at languages (with regard to any aspects it, whether teaching, learning etc)     , Give the section IX link.

Comment: Sam: The full OED doesn't have links to specific sub-definitions within a single entry, and there are several thousand lines in their webpage for the ***FOR** prep., conj., noun, adverb* entry. But if you search the page for, say, "with regard" you'd get straight to it. Assuming you have access in the first place - it's subscription-only, and if I didn't have access through my local library, that would cost me hundreds of pounds a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has no special meaning. The preposition "for" simply *collocates* with the noun "gift" when you want to indicate what area the talent is in. There's no logic or reason behind it, only tradition. This is why prepositions are one of the hardest parts of English to learn.

Answer (score 1):

*For* simply indicate *what* the mentioned gift / talent is for.
So _she has a gift for languages -> she is very good at (learning) languages

It is used together with other words as well, like flair:

> He has a flair for style -> he has a good sense of style
> She has a flair for grand parties -> she is good at organizing grand parties

Comment: What is the meaning of "for" in these sentence?

Comment: I can say she is very good at (teaching languages) instead of (learning languages).

Comment: What would be the meaning of _for_ in "a knife is for cutting" or "a book is for reading"? It's as good as the same as in your sentence. Either you are looking way to deep into this, or I do not understand what the source of your confusion is...

Comment: You said it means —she is very good at (learning) languages, I am saying it might also mean—she is very good at (teaching) languages

Comment: Yes, it might mean that as well. But usually "she has a gift for languages" means she can learn them well. It _could_ be used to indicate she speaks them well, writes them well, teaches them well, or even invents them well, but those are not the most common usages.